# Change Radio Button Color and Glyphicons When Button Clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, colors, radio-button

I have problem in my website application base on CodeIgniter and Bootstrap.

I want to change color when my radio button pressed.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">              
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="1" id="radio1<? echo $i; ?>"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          Benar 
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-success">
          <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="0" checked id="radio2<? echo $i; ?>"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          Tidak
          </label>              
          </div>
```

When I press Button `Benar` color will change to `Red` and also happen when I pressed button `Tidak`.

Answer (score -1):

I will recommend you to use javascript. It is more simple and useful.

You will need to add a onclick listener to your radio button like this :

```
    <label class="btn btn-primary BenarRadio">
       <input type="radio" onclick="changeColor();" name="jawaban[<?php echo $i ?>]"              value="1" id="radio1<? echo $i; ?>"> 
    Benar 
   </label>
```

After, you add the function changeColor() inside the same file so you can put this code
on the top of the file.

```
<script>
 function changeColor() {
     var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('BenarRadio');
     radio[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';

 }
</script>
```

Comment: You have to include the script inside the code or import the file in your page. Look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/V8P8a/

Comment: Did you try the script that I link? @RonAshrovy